# Why isn't my jquery dialog box working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I've been trying to figure out how to get a jquery dialog box to work.  For the life of me, I can't get it to work.  Here is some html with in-line javascript I've written:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function showDialog() {  
            $('#dialogBox').dialog();  
        }  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="showDialog();" />

<div id="dialogBox">
    <p>This is the text of my dialog box.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button in Internet Explorer, it says `Object doesn't support this property of method.`  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the dialog() function is part of jQuery UI, and it doesn't look like your code references the UI library.  Try adding something like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the `<head>` below where you reference the jQuery library.  This will pull in the Google-hosted version of the source.

I would imagine that the Google-hosted version includes lots of things you don't need, so you might be able to speed up loading times by [downloading your own copy](http://jqueryui.com/download) and only selecting the components that you need.

Comment: Accepted: That's correct, I didn't know that jquery and jquery UI were two different script libraries.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this to open,

```
 function showDialog() {  
        jq('#dialogBox').dialog('open');  
    }
```

or to close

```
    function showDialog() {  
        jq('#dialogBox').dialog('close');  
    }
```